# Use xlrd to convert XLSX to XML

Tags: python, xml, excel, xlrd

I want to make a Python script which uses `xlrd` to open a workbook and convert each worksheet to a separate XML file.

The Excel sheet can contain integer values, floats and strings. When I open the XLS file using `xlrd.open_workbook()` I loop through all cells in the worksheet and read the values.

When I check the types of the cell values it seems as if there are only floats or strings. Also all integer values seem to be converted into floats.

Is it possible to read the cell values as they appear in Excel?

Comment: Yes I did read the documentation. The problem is not in finding the difference between a cell with text and cells with a value.
I want to check if the cell contains a integer value or floating point value.

Comment: Then, per my answer, you can't. There is no discernible difference between a cell containing `1` and a cell containing `1.0`.

Comment: Note that Excel itself does not have an integer type.  **EVERY** number in Excel (including dates) is stored as a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Cell-class), `xlrd` supports only seven types of cell value (`Cell.ctype`), including

> `XL_CELL_NUMBER` `2` (`float`)

There is no separate `ctype` for integers. All numerical types (including dates, which are `ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE`) from Excel will be represented as `float` objects in Python. You can check if they are equal to an integer using:

```
cell.value.is_integer()
```

For example:

```
>>> 1.0.is_integer()
True
>>> 1.1.is_integer()
False
```